# jquery cookies / javascript cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm have planned to design a jewelry website with add to cart option. but i still don't know how to keep the selected items on the cart even after refreshing the page through jquery. so if anyone knew please provide an step by step example or tutorial.

Comment: Well.. you answered your own question, sort of. You can use cookies. Or localStorage. You could AJAX it to server side like PHP.

Comment: You would have to persist that information somewhere.  Cookies, session state, database, files, etc.

Comment: See: [SimpleCart](http://simplecartjs.org/) "A free and open-source javascript shopping cart that easily integrates with your current website."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple JQuery get method which links to a PHP file which adds the product to the Site cookies; when you want to view the cart, explode the cookie.

An example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#product").click(function(){
        // However you want to get the item ID
        var itemID = document.getElementById("productID").value;
        $.get("/inc/addtocart.php", { item: itemID }, function(data){
             document.getElementById("result-sec").innerHTML=data;
        });
   });           
 });
```

Your PHP file will look like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['item'])){
    $_COOKIE['cart_ids'] = $_COOKIE['cart_ids'] . '::' . $_GET['item'];
}
```

To view your cart items, simply:

```
$all_items = explode("::", $_COOKIE['cart_ids']);
foreach($all_items as $item):
    echo $item . "<br />";
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Now i got the idea!!

Comment: Not a problem, hope you achieve what you need! I'd also suggest putting it into a function like: show_items() so your front end development is easier.